# How to automatically switch off default display and set resolution if I connect a specific display?

Tags: scripts, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr, external-monitor

Everytime I connect to a specific external monitor, the default resolution is not the one I want, and I have to set it again.

How do I save a specific resolution for a specific display, and switch off my default display if I connect that display?

Comment: how did you set the resolution?

Comment: Would a backround script be fine with you?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Using Settings > Display

Comment: @JacobVlijm: If there's no better solution then yeah sure

Comment: Could you: i) post the output of `xrandr`, after you set up your screens correctly, and ii) make an educated guess what is your default screen? (in the output)? This often happens due to minor incompatibilities. The script is extremely light weight, so no need to worry about load.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: well, I'm not sure how to "set up screens correctly". Basically, there are two cases. The first is when no external display is connected, in which I want a specific resolution for the laptop's internal display. The second is when a specific monitor is connected by HDMI, in which I want only to use the external monitor, and I want a resolution to be set for it

Comment: @Lawand Aha, that makes it more interesting, and is a better justification to use a background script. For my understanding: 1. on connection of external screen: switch of screen A, set resolution for screen B. 2. if disconnected: switch on screen A and set resolution for screen A? If so, Please add from both situations the output of  `xrandr`, e.g. on https://pastebin.com/.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Case1: https://pastebin.com/FiAwSgQG Case2: https://pastebin.com/4EtYXbBg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Set resolution, depending on the presence of a (specific) attached screen

Below two options:

1. Set screen resolution and switch screen (automatic detection of second screen) by a shortcut key
2. Run a background script to automatically switch off the main screen and change the resolution

#### Option 1; shortcut

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# set the default screen
default = "DVI-I-1"
# set the specific external screen
external = "VGA-1"
# set the resolution of the single screen setup
singleres = "1680x1050"
# set the resolution of the specific external screeen
extrares = "1280x1024"

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")

def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(cmd)

def get_screens():
    return [l.split()[0] for l in get("xrandr").splitlines() if " connected" in l]

def set_screen(n_scr, screens):
    if n_scr == 1:
        run(["xrandr", "--output", default, "--auto"])
        run(["xrandr", "-s", singleres])
        print("1 screen")
    elif all([n_scr == 2, external in screens]):    
        run(["xrandr", "--output", default, "--off"])
        run(["xrandr", "-s", extrares])
        print("2 screens")

screens = get_screens()
n_scr2 = len(screens)
set_screen(n_scr2, screens)
```

#### Option 2; a background version

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# set the default screen
default = "DVI-I-1"
# set the specific external screen
external = "VGA-1"
# set the resolution of the single screen setup
singleres = "1680x1050"
# set the resolution of the specific external screeen
extrares = "1280x1024"

def get(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

def run(cmd):
    subprocess.call(cmd)

def get_screens(scrdata):
    return [l.split()[0] for l in scrdata.splitlines() if " connected" in l]

def set_screen(n_scr, screens):
    if n_scr == 1:
        run(["xrandr", "--output", default, "--auto"])
        run(["xrandr", "-s", singleres])
        print("1 screen")
    elif all([n_scr == 2, external in screens]):    
        run(["xrandr", "--output", default, "--off"])
        run(["xrandr", "-s", extrares])
        print("2 screens")

n_scr1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(4)
    scrdata = get("xrandr")
    if scrdata:
        screens = get_screens(scrdata)
        n_scr2 = len(screens)
        if n_scr2 != n_scr1:
            set_screen(n_scr2, screens)
        n_scr1 = n_scr2
```

#### How to use

1. Copy either one of the scripts above into an empty file, save it as `set_screens.py`
2. Replace in the head section of the script the values for:

   ```py
   # set the default screen
   default = "DVI-I-1"
   # set the specific external screen
   external = "VGA-1"
   # set the resolution of the single screen setup
   singleres = "1680x1050"
   # set the resolution of the specific external screeen
   extrares = "1280x1024"
   ```

   (the current settings are just for my test setup)
3. Test- run and apply the script:

   - ***if you use option 1, the shortcut***:

     Open a terminal, run the script subsequently with and without the external screen, with the command:

     ```
     python3 /path/to/set_screens.py
     ```

     It should set the screens as intended.

     Subsequently add, if all works fine, the script to a shortcut: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

     ```
     python3 /path/to/set_screens.py
     ```
   - ***if you use option 2, the background script***:

     Open a terminal, run the script with the command:

     ```
     python3 /path/to/set_screens.py
     ```

     and connect / disconnect the external monitor. It should change the resolution and switch on / off your default monitor as intended.

     Subsequently add, if all works fine, the script to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

     ```
     /bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && python3 /path/to/set_screens.py"
     ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the scripts. Two notes: When running the background script, there's some overhead to running xrandr to get the screens. Everytime it's run, the mouse lags a bit and the system does too. No idea if there's a solution to that, as it effects the usability of the script. The other thing is that sometimes when I run the script, it crashes with this output: https://pastebin.com/xUkrDPcK This happened twice.

Comment: The same error happens sometimes with the first script too

Comment: Hi @Lawand fixed the crashes on the background version for sure. The mouse hickups you experience seems to be related to minor incompatibilities with the video card. It does not occur on my 10+ year old system. Still looking for an alternative to get monitor info, Gtk/Gdk did not work out well so far.

Comment: @Lawand wait, I can detect screen setup changes with `wmctrl -d` ,keep xrandr outside the loop. Will post if I am done doing my taxes :)